# How to highlight a table cell (TD) when radio button is clicked with JavaScript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm developing an online baseball/softball scorebook application.  I want to visually change the CSS of the specific table cell (a specific TD) when the user changes the value of one of the radio buttons inside that TD is selected.

Here is a JPG of what the table looks like:  http://www.ppgeez.com/images/gt_ab.jpg

There are 12 players and each player can have a maximum of 6 AB's.  The code below is an example of a single At-Bat (AB) for a player where you can specify what the player did for that particular AB.

```
    <td>
  <table border=1>
    <tr>
      <td>
    <table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
        <tr><td><input type=radio name=p1o1 value="1B">1B
            <td><input type=radio name=p1o1 value="FO">FO
        <tr><td><input type=radio name=p1o1 value="2B">2B
            <td><input type=radio name=p1o1 value="GO">GO
        <tr><td><input type=radio name=p1o1 value="3B">3B
            <td><input type=radio name=p1o1 value="FC">FC
        <tr><td><input type=radio name=p1o1 value="HR">HR
            <td><input type=radio name=p1o1 value="SF">SF
        <tr><td><input type=radio name=p1o1 value="BB">BB
            <td><input type=radio name=p1o1 value="K" >K
        <tr><td><input type=radio name=p1o1 value="RE">RE
            <td><input type=radio name=p1o1 value="DP">DP
   </table>

      <td valign=top align=center>
        Run<br><input type=checkbox name=p1run1><br><hr>
        RBIs<br><select name=p1rbi1>
                <option value=0>0
                <option value=1>1
                <option value=2>2
                <option value=3>3
                <option value=4>4
                </select><p>
        <input type=radio name=p1o1 value="NA" checked>N/A
      <td>

  </table>
<td>
```

I'm want to visually highlight (by changing the background color of the TD) each AB that is 'completed'.  Basically, when the form loads, the "N/A" radio button is selected by default.  If any other radio button is selected (1B, 2B, K, etc...) then that TD should be highlighted.  If N/A is selected again, it should be unhighlighted.  I'm not sure where to start, any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

**UPDATE**: Final Working Code - I used a function from below, but since I was using nested tables the trick was to select the specific one I wanted using **eq**(*x*).

```
    $("td input[type=radio]").change(function () {
  function clearTable(){
  var table = $(this).parents('table:eq(0)');
    $(table).removeClass('selected');
  }
  $('input[value="NA"]').click(clearTable);
  var table = $(this).parents('table:eq(1)');
  if (this.value != 'NA') {    
    table.addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

**UPDATE - GIVE ALL TABLES SPECIFIC CLASS**

// set each table with the atBat class
ABtables = $('input[type="checkbox"]').closest('table');
ABtables.each(function() { $(this).addClass('atBat'); });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table cell highlight

```
$(function(){
  function clearTable(){
    $('td.selected', table).removeClass('selected');
  }
  var table=$('input[value="1B"]').closest('table');
  $('input[value="NA"]').click(clearTable);
  $(':radio', table).click(function(){
    clearTable();
    $(this).closest('td').addClass('selected');
  });
});
```

**EDITED CODE IN RESPONSE TO COMMENTS**

```
//assuming you've given the class atBat to any table which might be selected
$('table.atBat').each(function(){
  var table=$(this);//cache the current iteration
  var childTable=table.find('table:first');
   //replace above click handler with this
   $(':radio', childTable).click(function(){
    if ($(this).val()==='NA'){
      table.removeClass('selected');
    }
    else {
     table.addClass('selected');
    }
   });
})
```

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: This was basically the solution I used.  One thing that this code did was remove classes from ALL elements that were previously hilighted, when I wanted it removed from specific tables.  Worked like a charm with a couple edits.

Comment: arrrgghhh!  Doesn't work in IE!!!  Looks like something with the eq...

Any ideas how I can figure that out?

Comment: I updated the original post with the 'working' code :)  Its only working in FF...  In IE, I can click on radio button that is != NA, and nothing happens.  If I click a 2nd radio button != NA, then it properly highlights using the addClass.  

The clearTable/removeClass function seems to work in all browsers once something actually gets the addClass applied, but its taking multiple clicks (2) to get it applied.  Any ideas would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: The `clearTable` function should be defined outside of any click/change handlers. The way your code is set up now it defines the function and binds the click inside the `change` func. These should be separated. i.e. set table var -> then bind NA click -> then bind change field. You should also use a different variable name inside the handler (instead of `table`). Let me know if you have any troubles and I'll update my post.

Comment: Hmm...maybe you can look at the test page directly:  http://ppgeez.com/stats/enter_game.php

Basically, there is one main table, and then inside each of that tables TD's contains 2 nested tables.  The radio boxes are in a table themselves, and the checkbox and N/A radio button are in another.  Thats why, when I turn OFF the highlighting, I had to find the 0th parent, instead of the 1st parent like I use to turn it on.  Check it out... if you can update your code so I can see how its done, that would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: I looked at your code. I think you should give each table (that will toggle 'selected' a common class like 'atBat' and target from there. I will edit my original post with my suggested code. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: PERFECT!  All I had to do was add code that gave each AB table the 'atBat' class, and it worked great. (I will add this code to my original post).  Thank you so much.

I'll add

Answer (score 1):

You could just use this jQuery (untested, but should work):

```
$(document).ready(function() {          

    $("td input[type=radio]").change(function () {
        var td = $(this).parent();
        td.css("background", "#000");
    }); 
});
```

Also, as one of the other answers mentioned, you need to close your td and other html tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a javascript function that does this.  First, check to see which one is selected, then (in a loop) get the TD.  Once you have those 2 things, the rest is easy.

Here is some code to get you started:

first, you'll need to add an event handler to each radio button that points it to this function -

```
function handleRadioClick(e) {
    var ev = e || window.event;

    //ev.srcElement will give you the radio button clicked
    //This code will get you the TD
    var obj = ev.srcElement;
    while (obj && obj.parentElement && obj.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'td') {
        obj = obj.parentElement
    }

    //at this point, obj should be the TD
}
```

I didn't do it all for you, but it should get you started.

EDIT:

I just realized that you have the radio buttons in their own TD inside of a table, inside of the TD you're after.  You'll have to modify my code to get the table and then get its parent (the TD your after).

Answer (score 0):

First, it looks like you are missing closing tags on a lot of your markup.  Specifically the closing td and option tags.

With jquery, you can change the background color of the td when selected:

```
<input type="radio" name="p1o1" value="1B" onclick="$(this).parent().css('background', 'yellow');" />
```

Then to clear the selected backgrounds you would want to give write a function that, when the user clicks the N/A radio button does something like:

```
var $kids = $('#mytableid').children();
$kids.css("background", "#FFF");
```